# In a ListTitle PopupMenuButton works in debug but not in release mode in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, popupmenubutton

It's working when I keep it in AppBar. But in ListTile it's not working.

It's working in debug build not working in release build. May I know what's the issue exactly..

In my case when I add PopupMenuButton the button itself not showing in release build.

```
Widget popupMenu() {
    return PopupMenuButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.more_vert,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onSelected: (value) {
          //conditions check
         
        },
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 'Message',
                  child: Text(
                    'Message',
                  )),
            ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was in a ListTitle PopupMenuButton was not taking. I have added a row and inside a row I have added ListTitle container with width and PopupMenuButton.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
                  child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        dense: true,

                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                popupMenu(aspirantCardVO),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }


Widget popupMenu() {
    return PopupMenuButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.more_vert,
          size: 30,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        onSelected: (value) {
          //conditions check
         
        },
        itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                  value: 'Message',
                  child: Text(
                    'Message',
                  )),
            ]);
  }
```